# Custom Textview Font not working

Tags: java, android, fonts, textview

I want to using other font on the textview. I already Created custom textview class and created fonts folder.The problem is the font not changed after compiled.I dont know what mistake that i make.I hope you guys can help me solve this problem.Thank you in advance

[image]

[image]

**activity_example_one.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.khoi.androidexample.example.Example_One_Activity">

    <com.khoi.androidexample.custom.TextViewBold
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/texview_bold_id"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>

    <com.khoi.androidexample.custom.TextViewMedium
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/textview_medium_id"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Example_One_Activity.java**

```
public class Example_One_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


    TextViewBold textViewBold;
    TextViewMedium textViewMedium;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_example_one);
        textViewBold = (TextViewBold) findViewById(R.id.texview_bold_id);
        textViewMedium = (TextViewMedium) findViewById(R.id.textview_medium_id);
    }

}
```

**TextViewBold.java**

public class TextViewBold extends TextView {

```
public  TextViewBold(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    init(context);
}

public  TextViewBold(Context context,AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context,attrs);
    init(context);
}

public TextViewBold(Context context){
    super(context);
    init(context);
}


private void init(Context context) {
    if (!isInEditMode()) {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"Lato_Medium.ttf");
        setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-download font style and replace the file inside fonts folder and it worked.Thank you very much for helping solved this problem

Answer (score 1):

You are missing "fonts/" from your address , it should be like this :

```
         setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"fonts/Lato_Medium.ttf"));
```

Comment: I got an error message :  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found fonts/Lato_Medium.ttf

Comment: try rebuild the project , then copy the exact code i edited above , it should works, i cant see any problem in the code

Answer (score 1):

Pass context in your **init(Context context)**

And getAssets() like --> context.getAssets()

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"Lato_Medium.ttf");
```

isInEditMode() -->Ensure it will return true

Comment: I already add context as parameter and !isInEditMode() retun true, but textview font still not changed.

Comment: pls check once again without if(! isInEditMode()) and update me soon

Comment: if isInEditMode() only its return false.

Comment: Hold the ctrl key & move your mouse cursor into "Lato_Medium.ttf" if you click that text it will open the file or not? Pls confirm me I will give the solution.

Comment: The file is opened.

Comment: Your code looks right. No problem in code. Check your ttf file. Check same code with other font file. Please update your question code. Because you use wrong one - getResources().getAssets(). So please update your question code